# react-router link to sub route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

How do I create a link for sub route like lang -> python ?

**My routes**

```
var routes = (
  <Route name="app" path="/" handler={ App }>
    <Route name="info" handler={ Info } />
    <Route name="home" handler={ Home } />
    <Route name="lang" handler={ Lang } >
      <Route path="java" handler={Lang}/>
      <Route path="python" handler={Lang}/>
    </Route>
    <DefaultRoute handler={ Home } />
    <NotFoundRoute handler={ NotFound } />
  </Route>
);
```

Creating a link to info or lang works fine but how do I link to java or python ?

```
<Link to="info">Info</Link>
```

I tested

```
<Link to="lang/java">Java</Link>
<Link to="lang java">Java</Link>
```

but it results in an error:

Invariant Violation: Cannot find a route named "lang/java"

A normal link works, but I would like to know how it is done with Link.

```
<a href="#lang/python">
   <h2>PYTHON</h2>
</a>
```

**Solution**

the link:

```
<Link to="java">
  JAVA
</Link>
```

the routes:

```
<Route name="challenge" handler={ Challenge } >

      <Route name="java" path="java" handler={Challenge}/>
```

But maybe someone has a solution without adding a new name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add a name "java" to link "java".

Or a better way is to create a parameter in the lang route path="lang/:language" and then get the language out in the handler

Comment: Adding a name to my subroute helped. I will think about it lang/:language, but i want to use different handlers for each lang. Thx

Comment: @fuubah you can still use use `lang/:language` as a route. You would have a single handler that checks `this.props.params.language` but render different components based on that prop.